# How to create new column based on first column taking into account size of letter and list in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
--------
John Simon prd
agc Ann White
BeN and Ann

bad_list = ["Ben", "Wayne"]
```

And I need to ake something like: create new column "col2" and if value in "col1" has value from bad_list give "1" in "col2" for this row and 0 if not.

***Be aware thatn size of letter in bad_list and "col1" should be ignored, for example in "col1" is value "BeN" and on bad_list is "Ben" so it should also have value "1" in "col2"***

So as a result based on Data Frame and conditions above I need as a result like below:

```
col1            | col2
----------------|------
John Simon prd  |0
arc Ann White   |0
BeN and Ann     |1
```

last row in "col2" has value "1" because "Ben" is on bad_list nevermind that in "col1" is written as BeN.
How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: Slightly change the solution below to:  `import re 
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.contains('|'.join(bad_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE).astype(int)`   The main change is adding `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to instruct Pandas to ignore case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try via `str.title()`,`str.contains()` and `astype()` method:

```
df['col2']=df['col1'].str.title().str.contains('|'.join(bad_list)).astype(int)
```

output of `df`:

```
    col1            col2
0   John Simon prd  0
1   agc Ann White   0
2   BeN and Ann     1
```

**Step by step breakdown of code:**

Since your list i.e bad_list contains word in format(Ist word is capital and rest all small) so we convert whole Series('col1') like that by using `Series.str.title()` so now the Series('col1') looks like:

```
0    John Simon Prd
1     Agc Ann White
2       Ben And Ann
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Then we use `str.contains()` that gives us a boolean series after checking if any of the element inside bad_list is present in the row of Series('col1'):

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

**Note:**

here the code inside `contains()` method:

```
'|'.join(bad_list)
#giving you a string(output of above code):
'Ben|Wayne'
```

Finally we are typecasting boolean Series to int via `astype()` method:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

**OR**

another way is to use `IGNORECASE` flag from `re` module as suggested by @seanbean in comments:

```
from re import IGNORECASE

df['col2']=df['col1'].str.contains('|'.join(bad_list), flags=IGNORECASE).astype(int)
```